# Finding out the data a row has been inserted into a table

Tags: sql-server

Is there a way to find out the data a row has been inserted (into a SQL Server 2005, 2008 or 2008 r2) database table? Without setting up auditing (either ootb or custom 3rd party product).

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if you want to be notified when the row is inserted make insert trigger to this table.

Answer (score 4):

You can always create a trigger on that table.  Like so:

```
create trigger InsertNotification
on YourTable
after insert

as

    -- do whatever you want when an insert happens

go
```

This can definitely be seen as a form of "auditing", but I'm not familiar with "ootb", nor is this a 3rd party product.  Triggers are the way to go.

Comment: "ootb" = "out of the box" --> a feature that's included with SQL Server (= the opposite of a 3rd party tool)

Comment: @ChristianSpecht Nice, thanks for the clarification.  I have never heard of that acronym before!

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to save the information when a specific row was inserted, you could just create a new `datetime` or `smalldatetime` column with `getdate()` as the default value.
Whenever a new row is inserted, this column will be automatically filled with the current date/time.

Advantages:

- no trigger or 3rd party tool needed

Disadvantages:

- this only works for new tables (or all new records in existing tables). If a table already has existing records, you won't have an insert date/time for them
- if you want this for all your tables, you have to insert the column into each table